# Visibility of existing autofresh connected sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

My organisation is facing issues with running out of slots allocated Monday morning running GCP queries and we suspect this is partially due to the number of autofresh connected sheets that have been set and forgotten. We may need to ask Google to get a list of all the autofresh queries and the creators, but before we get to that, is there a way for users to check themselves first ?(Personally I have got a few queries set up as autofresh last year but now I can't remember what they are, let alone cancelling them. )
Thanks in advance.